# How to import *.so binary in React Native for Android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

The manufacturer gave me an audio codec binary 'libasc_decoder.so'. From what I've read, binary can just be included in 'main/jniLibs', and it'll be automatically compiled with the project. Then I just have to call `System.loadLibrary("asc_decoder")`. I built apk and analyzed apk, and I see the binary file in lib folder. However, when I call the native method `init()`, I get error 'implementation not found'.

I also see suggestions to just name it 'libs' instead of 'jniLibs', and add sourceSet in 'app/build.gradle'

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['./src/main/libs']
    jni.srcDirs = []
  }
}
```

In both cases, when I run 'Analyze APK...' in android studio. I can see the binary was successfully compiled. but when below code doesn't load any binary method at all

```
public class ASCDecoder {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("asc_decoder");
  }

  public final static int ASC_I = 1;
  public final static int ASC_II = 2;
  public final static int ASC_III = 3;
  public final static int ASC_IV = 4;
  public final static int ASC_V = 5;
  public final static int ASC_VI = 6;
  public final static int ASC_VII = 7;

  public native short init(short codec);
  public native int readHead(short[] bytes);
  public native short[] decode(short[] bytes, short len, short codec);
  public native static void destroy();
}
```

Comment: So when using JNI, they generally give you the java side class as well.  THe method names, class name, and the parameters of the class all have to match with the names of the functions in the library.  That error is due to them not matching

Comment: This (`ASCDecoder`) was the Java side class they gave me.

Comment: Is it the same name, including package?

Comment: The original name was libASCDecoder.so. I tried that, it didn't work, and I saw that convention was lowercase, so I changed it to lower case. Neither case worked...